# Forwarding Logstash requests to Elasticsearch with user\pass

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin {} } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] } }'
```

This returns 401 access denied as I have credentials turned on.
I'm having a bit of a trouble adding credentials to this line. Would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -e 'input {  stdin {} } output { elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] user => YOURUSERNAME password => YOURPASSWORD } }'
```

Now it works.